# jQuery Ajax - Unexpected Token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm trying to make an AJAX GET request to [this URL](http://hndroidapi.appspot.com/news/format/json/page/) and process the JSON response. If you visit that URL directly, it works. I've also tried running it through [Hurl It](http://hurt.it), and [it works](http://hurl.it/hurls/98417427b23fa1d963487dcc11211fe791727aba/e0346a991588ba2966dcfcf43de592447565a1d0) too.

I'm there for at a loss as to why I can't make a `JSON` / `JSONP` request to it through jQuery.

I initially tried to make a JSON response but get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hndroidapi.appspot.com/news/format/json/page/. Origin http://hackernews.dev is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

So therefore I took an attempt at JSONP, and get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  hndroidapi.appspot.com:1
```

Line 1 is the entire JSON response, in one line, but **not** wrapped in a callback. Hence, it seems this API does not support JSONP.

Hence, is there anything I can do to solve this? I'm a little stumped unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's a way round this.

My code is as follows:

```
var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
  url: "http://hndroidapi.appspot.com/news/format/json/page/",
  dataType: "jsonp" 
});
ajaxReq.done(function(d) {
  console.log("DONE", d);
});
ajaxReq.error(function(d) {
  console.log("ERROR", d);
});
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: so you are getting "Unexpected token :" error on the json response, right? Sounds like it's not properly formatted json.

Comment: you can run your response through jsonlint.com and see exactly where your issue is.

Comment: If I run it through JSON Lint, it says the JSON is valid. I believe the error is around a missing callback parameter.

Comment: You can't do a JSONP request unless the server supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api definitely does not support JSONP (unless i'm missing something, not too familiar with python) : https://github.com/glebpopov/Hacker-News-Droid-API/blob/master/Formatter.py your only option at this point is to either use YQL or a server-side proxy

Comment: Yeah, this is it. Maybe I could fork it and add JSONP support. Amazing HN doesn't have its own API! . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make AJAX requests to sites other than the one your web page was delivered from for security reasons.

Comment: You can using JSONP with callbacks, but it seems this server doesn't support it. I'm wondering if there's a way around it at all.

Answer (score 0):

try to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ , not sure.

Comment: The request is a GET request.